# Can Xcode combine speech recognition and automation?

Tags: xcode, ui-automation

Is there a way to *tell* Xcode to execute an action?

If I could do that, I could build a plugin that makes my development much faster, with sentences like: "create a new test" or "create a GPU class". *A step towards J.A.R.V.I.S.*

All I can find is voice recognition for iOS, but that's not what I'm searching for. This is the most similar topic and it is suggested to write external scripts: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7835/automating-repetitive-game-development-tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, on Yosemite it seems I can run automated commands on Xcode via Automator. I will probably need to setup some keyboard shortcuts to make it work well.